# In the OSGi/iPOJO world, how to get a list of instances of classes implementing an interface?

Tags: java, osgi, inject, reflections, ipojo

In the JavaEE/CDI world, I know how to have the list of instances of classes implementing a given interface : by using `Instance<MyInterface>` combined with [reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library.

But in the OSGI/iPOJO world, how to do so ?

I know I get one instance by using `@Requires MyInterface anInstance`. But how can I have a programmatic access to all those classes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `BundleContext`:

```
@Context BundleContext context;

public List<ServiceReference> getInstancesImplementingX() {
    return context.getServiceReferences(X.class);   
}
```

Comment: Unfortnuatly, this requires all my loaded classes to be services, which I did not expected ...

Comment: How, there is a way without having to load the class: context.getServiceReferences("name.of.my.class", null);

It returns an array, null if no service matches.